# Rails search association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a simple search form in my Rails app and right now it lets me search a Pdform attribute. A pdform belongs to a user so there is a `user_id` in the pdform model.

How can I search a users `first_name` and have it bring up all of the pdforms that belong to them?

This is how I have it setup.

#### Routes

```
get '/pdforms/history', to: 'pdforms#history'
```

#### Views

```
<%= form_tag pdforms_history_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

#### Pdforms controller

```
def history
    @pdforms = Pdform.search(params[:search])
  end
```

#### Pdform Model

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    self.where("user.first_name like ?", "%#{search}%")
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Given that syntax-wise calling a method and reading a local variable are indistinguishable, I'd strongly advise having different name for an argument of `search`, such as `query`. Not that it should be a problem now.

Comment: Is your user logged in? If so, are you using Devise? Or, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming an admin (as mentioned in your comment) should have a search capability whereas a regular user should just be able to see their own Pdforms.

So, perhaps your view could include something like:

```
<% if is_admin? %>
  <%= form_tag pdforms_history_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search', :name => nil %>
  <% end %>  
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'List', pdforms_history_path %>
<% end %>
```

And then your controller could do something like (borrowing liberally from AntonTkachov's answer):

```
def history
  if params[:search] and is_admin?
    @pdforms = self.joins(:user).where("users.first_name LIKE ? OR users.last_name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  else
    @pdforms = Pdform.where(user: current_user)
  end
end
```

NOTE: That whole `is_admin?` thing is just an example. You would need to make sure you actually have such a method/helper available - which I don't know if you do. Also, you should decide if you want to do `is_admin?` again in `if params[:search] and is_admin?`, just to make sure the user isn't monkeying around with the URL.

And, then you should have a `views/pdforms/_history.html.erb` that renders the `@pdforms` nicely. Like, perhaps, with each Pdform on a single row of a table.

Comment: I do like this answer. However this is not just history for that specific user. Admins will use this tab to search different users pdforms as a 'papertrail'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    self.joins(:user).where("users.first_name LIKE ? OR users.last_name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

Comment: If the OP has a user w/ `first_name: "Jonathan"` and `last_name: "Westin"` and another user w/ `first_name: "Jonah"` and `last_name: "West"` and both users have PDFs, what happens when the user named Jonathan Westin submits a search of `Jon West`?

Comment: Is your user logged in? If so, are you using Devise? Or, something else?

Comment: @jvillian A user must be logged in to do anything. I am using Devise.